# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException : 'o.s.b.a.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration' is defined when started spring boot

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-boot

I have an application consisting of two modules:

1/logic: spring-core, spring-data-Neo4j

2/presentation: spring-boot

The declartion of spring beans in the first module is done through an xml file. This file is imported into the file context of the second module. Below is my setup:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource(value = "application-context-presentation-all.xml")
public class Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

application-context-presentation-all.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"         xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:spring/application-context-logic-all.xml" />

 </beans>
```

application-context-logic-all.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

 <import resource="application-context-logic-db.xml"/>
 <import resource="application-context-logic-repo.xml"/>
 <import resource="application-context-logic-facade.xml"/>

 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/spring/environment.properties" />

 </beans>
```

I shared the project on [github](https://github.com/AndolsiZied/hotel-booking) for more details.

When I run the class Application, spring boot started but it thorw the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:959)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.requiresEagerInitForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:454)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:383)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:354)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:156)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:144)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:113)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:44)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:136)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:107)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
at com.ando.booking.presentation.Application.main(Application.java:18)
```

Comment: Did you miss a repository declaration (can't find `com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-neo4j:jar:0.7.10-SNAPSHOT`)?

Comment: In fact it is a [project](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit) that I used for unit test. It can fill the neo4j database.

Comment: I can see that. But I can't build your project because it can't find that dependency. Did you forget to declare the repository for it?

Comment: I installed it in the local repository

Comment: This looks to be a bug. I've opened an issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1054) so that we can track the problem. Thanks for letting us know about it.